# What is the RowState value (if it's currently 'Added') after RejectChanges has been called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rowstate

So, I'm doing an exam preparation on c# ASP.Net and I stumbled upon a question, which seemed rather easy, up until I decided to check it out.

"What will be the state of a row (RowState), which is currently in state Added, after the method RejectChanges has been called?"

a) Unmodified

b) Detached

c) Added

d) Modified

Now, when I first thought about it, I assumed that a row is inserted to a data collection, it's state is thus Added and upon revoking the changes with the method RejectChanges and thus removing the newly added row, I assume that the state of the collection would be Unmodified and the actual state of the row will be Detached, since it's not longer present in the collection.

I then investigated this further and from the MSDN I found:

"When RejectChanges is called, all rows with a row state of Added are removed. The remaining rows are given a row state of Unchanged"

So from this, a) Unmodified = Unchanged.

But then, I checked how a row can get the state Unchanged:

"The RowState of a newly created row is set to Detached. After the new DataRow is added to the DataRowCollection by calling the Add method, the value of the RowState property is set to Added.

Detached is also set for a row that has been removed from a DataRowCollection using the Remove method, or by the Delete method followed by the AcceptChanges method."

So, from this it follows that it should be b) Detached.

PS: the question is not of any major importance to be honest, but I'm just really curious for the actual answer (and the reasoning behind it) and also if my initial logic is true.

Thank you for your time and sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: ADO.NET instead of ASP.NET? I don't see the difference between your assumption and your citations.

Comment: The changes of already existing rows, which might have been modified are reverted. The newly added row will be detached (if I remember correctly).

Comment: A datarowset in ADO.NET has no states like that, only a collection of "changes"

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase the question:
The current state of a row is "Added". The method RejectChanges is called. What is the state of the row now? We did have also lecture about how ASP reacts with ADO.